# Weird exception for NVARCHAR

Tags: sql-server, nvarchar

This one gives the exception: *'NVARCHAR' is not a recognized built-in function name.*

```
DECLARE @BatchIds TABLE
    (
      BatchId AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ,
      UserLogonId AS NVARCHAR(80) ,
      ReportStatus NVARCHAR(100) ,
      Created DATETIME ,
      RunTimeInMins AS INT ,
      ReportName NVARCHAR(200)
    )
```

When I remove the "AS" for NVARCHAR, it does not give any exception.

```
DECLARE @BatchIds TABLE
    (
      BatchId AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ,
      UserLogonId NVARCHAR(80) ,
      ReportStatus NVARCHAR(100) ,
      Created DATETIME ,
      RunTimeInMins AS INT ,
      ReportName NVARCHAR(200)
    )
```

Any suggestions as to why?

**Update:**

Please note that my question is more directed towards why AS works different in this situation behind the scenes than trying to solve a work situation.
For those who could not get the 2nd sample working, please try this. 
This gives me the same data I inserted without errors and the SQL Server version as 
*Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)....*

```
DECLARE @BatchIds TABLE
    (
      UserLogonId NVARCHAR(80) ,
      ReportStatus NVARCHAR(100) ,
      Created DATETIME
    )
INSERT  INTO @BatchIds
        ( UserLogonId ,
          ReportStatus ,
          Created
        )
VALUES  ( 'Test1' ,
          'Test2' ,
          '2012-08-08'
        )

SELECT  *
FROM    @BatchIds
SELECT  @@VERSION AS [Version]
```

Putting an AS in this query for NVARCHAR throws the same exception as above.

**UPDATE:**

This is resolved. This behaviour is only when you compile it and SQL Server allows you to compile this. But when you run it, then it throws an exception for any datatype using AS.

Comment: Even the 2nd one should give an exception .You cannot use aliasing for data type

Comment: @praveen: The 2nd one did not give any exception though.

Comment: That's pretty strange which sql version are u using ?? It should fail because aliasing is used for specifying the column name

Comment: `AS` in column definition is for computed columns.

Comment: And a [link to MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: My bad!! You know what, I just tried compiling and I see this behavior but when I run it, it does throw an exception for the AS for any datatype! Silly me.

Comment: Of course it does. An expression is expected after `AS`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need all those `AS` keywords that you had - just define your table variable like this:

```
DECLARE @BatchIds TABLE
(
  BatchId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ,
  UserLogonId NVARCHAR(80) ,
  ReportStatus NVARCHAR(100) ,
  Created DATETIME ,
  RunTimeInMins INT ,
  ReportName NVARCHAR(200)
)
```

When trying to run your sample #2 on my SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1 - Developer Edition), I get these errors:

> *Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>
>   Invalid column name 'UNIQUEIDENTIFIER'.*
>
> *Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>
>   Invalid column name 'INT'.*

I have to remove the `AS` keywords to make it work. Using `AS` is trying to define an **alias** for the column - but since that `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` or `INT` is a reserved keyword in SQL Server, you cannot use those as column aliases. Same for SQL Server 2012 Express - I get those errors, too, and cannot make it work unless I remove those unnecessary `AS` keywords

Comment: I get that. I am curious as to what happens behind the scenes where SQL Server allows some datatypes to be allowed to use AS while others are not allowed.

Comment: @Kash: those `as` keywords aren't needed - just don't use them. The `AS` typically defines an **alias**, e.g. for a table or a column in a query. It has absolutely no sense to use an `AS` in a declaration of a table variable. Your sample #2 doesn't even work on my machine, either (SQL Server 2008 R2) and gives errors - those `AS` aren't allowed for some types or not for others - they're just plain not needed and not valid.